# Plot of 3D matrix with colour scale - Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matplotlib

I would like to plot a 3D matrix - essentially a box of numbers, each labelled by an `x, y, z` triad of coordinates- by assigning a different colour to each of the `x, y, z` point, according to its magnitude (for example, bigger numbers in red and smaller numbers in blue). 
I cannot plot sections of the matrix, I rather need to plot the whole matrix together.

If we call `matrix3D` my matrix, its elements are built this way:

```
matrix3D[x][y][z] = np.exp(-(x**2+y**2+z**2))
```

How can I obtain the desired plot?

EDIT: Using Mayavi2 Contour3D(), I have tried to write the following:

```
from mayavi import mlab

X = np.arange(0, n_x, 1)
Y = np.arange(0, n_z, 1)
Z = np.arange(0, n_z, 1)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(X, Y, Z)
obj = mlab.contour3d(X, Y, Z, matrix3D, contours=4, transparent=True)
```

where `n_x, n_y, n_z` are the dimension of the 3 axes. How can I actually see and/or save the image now?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to plot the whole thing I think you're best taking a look at [mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html). This will let you plot a volume and you should be able to get the results you need.

I know you said you need to plot the whole thing at once, but this might still be of *some* use. You can use `countourf` to plot like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix3D = np.empty((10, 10, 10))
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
z = np.arange(10)
matrix3D[x][y][z] = np.exp(-(x**2+y**2+z**2))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(plt.subplot(1, 1, 1))
ax.contourf(x, y, matrix3D[:, :, 3])

plt.show()
```

This gives you a *slice* of the 3D matrix (in this example the 4th slice).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have a problem with mayavi (see edit). Can you help me? The contourf method is OK, as well, but I would like to concentrate on the fully 3D plot

Comment: @johnhenry I had a look but seem to be having the same problem as you. I get an image if I run the mayavi tests so I would guess that it's the way you're trying to view the data, but I'm afraid I can't be much more help than that.